# ESP32 - using MicroPython: How to update clock after reboot?

Tags: micropython, esp32

I have an ESP32 board, with Micropython installed properly, and connecting to local the internet.

Since it have to do a scheduled jobs- its clock need to be synced. After boot it get a generic date `1/1/2000`.

How can Micropython updates int clock using `ntp.pool.org` or other?

Guy

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=micropython+ntp found me https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2440 as the first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this post](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=5013&p=28765#p28739) on the Micropython forum:

> There is primitive NTP support in the ESP32 port (borrowed from the
>   ESP8266 port). In short:
>
> ```
> import ntptime 
> ntptime.settime()  # Synchronise the system time using NTP
> ```
>
> Caveat: There is no timezone support so the system time will be set to
>   UTC.

From [this discussion](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2440), you need to make sure you have an active internet connection before trying to set the time, and you should expect to get occasional timeout errors and handle these appropriately.

For reference the source of the `ntptime` module is [here](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/esp8266/modules/ntptime.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a DS3231 RTC. I’m currently using one and it works great.